# document.getElementById(" ").value doesnot work for flipswitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose, the user selects "M", how do i access that value in javascript. I am trying to use the traditional method, document.getElementById("gender").value  But it doesnt work.

Code:

```
<label for="gender">Gender</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="gender" name="mf" data-role="flipswitch" data-on-text="M" data-off-text="F"/>
```

Is there any equivalent method to access the value of the flipswitch?

Comment: You should paste some code we can look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yeah, the checkbox doesn’t currently have a value. I believe that the attribute you’re looking for isn’t `value` it should be `document.getElementById("gender").checked` to see if the checkbox is checked or not. This will return either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working exact you need. you can all as many check box as you want.

Trick is it's bound to class name `flipswitch` and get the value of `data-on-text` when checked and `data-off-text` when not checked.

```js
var flipswitch = document.getElementsByClassName("flipswitch");

    
var myFunction = function() {
 if(this.checked == 1) {
  alert(this.getAttribute("data-on-text"));
 } else {
  alert(this.getAttribute("data-off-text"));
 }
};
for(var i=0; i < flipswitch.length; i++){
 flipswitch[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<label for="gender">Gender</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="gender" value="1" name="mf" class="flipswitch" data-on-text="Male" data-off-text="Female"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="life" value="1" name="ml" class="flipswitch" data-on-text="Alive" data-off-text="Dead"/>
```

Comment: i have lots of this kind of flipswitch. i need a shorter way to access the values.